# Contact Form 7 Ajax/jquery Trigger Invalid - not being triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, contact-form-7

Coders,

I got a client that enjoys having Contact Form 7 as a plugin for forms. I can not say anythiong bad about that. Especially when I just got the Ajax to work as well.

But one thing does bother me. Development URL:
http://client.nyladesign.se/karlssonuddare2015/vardering/

```
$('.wpcf7').on('invalid.wpcf7 spam.wpcf7 mailsent.wpcf7 mailfailed.wpcf7 submit.wpcf7', function (e) {
        console.log("JQUERY / CF7  – Trigger", e.type);
});
```

The only thing being triggered here is the SUBMIT trigger. 
Even when the form is 'invalid' - there is no response to the invalid.wpcf7

How come? I need this to work, since I want to have som custom modal windows as responses to fail/success, and to try to hide CF7's own display of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "var $ = jQuery.noConflict();" somewhere before the footer include and removing multiple instances of jQuery fixed the problem for me.

Hope that helps